# R session does not start from Rstudio (no such file or directory)

Tags: r, rstudio

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.12.0+369 "Ocean Storm " (33206f75, 2023-12-17) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.12.0+369 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1.

Error output:

```
[No errors emitted]
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*/Users/kseniapiven/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-kseniapiven.log*

```
2023-05-20T16:38:32.544765Z [rsession-kseniapiven] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path: /Users/kseniapiven/.local/share/rstudio/sources/session-97cc9b94/CAE3277F]; OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::session::source_database::get(const std::string &, bool, boost::shared_ptr<SourceDocument>) src/cpp/session/SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:692; LOGGED FROM: SEXP rstudio::session::modules::source::(anonymous namespace)::rs_readSourceDocument(SEXP) src/cpp/session/modules/SessionSource.cpp:1436
2023-05-20T16:38:32.567967Z [rsession-kseniapiven] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path: /Users/kseniapiven/.local/share/rstudio/sources/session-97cc9b94/C3B958E7]; OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::session::source_database::get(const std::string &, bool, boost::shared_ptr<SourceDocument>) src/cpp/session/SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:692; LOGGED FROM: SEXP rstudio::session::modules::source::(anonymous namespace)::rs_readSourceDocument(SEXP) src/cpp/session/modules/SessionSource.cpp:1436
2023-05-20T16:38:32.567967Z [rsession-kseniapiven] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path: /Users/kseniapiven/.local/share/rstudio/sources/session-97cc9b94/C3B958E7]; OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::session::source_database::get(const std::string &, bool, boost::shared_ptr<SourceDocument>) src/cpp/session/SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:692; LOGGED FROM: SEXP rstudio::session::modules::source::(anonymous namespace)::rs_readSourceDocument(SEXP) src/cpp/session/modules/SessionSource.cpp:1436
```

I have used Rstudio before, last time it was a few months ago and now it doesn't want to start. I have uninstalled both R and Rstudio completely and installed again, but it didn't help. if I run R from Terminal it works fine. What should I try?

Comment: Try https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-resolve-rstudio-start-up-error-r-session-process-exited-neri

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that RStudio has trouble accessing session data under `~/.local/share/rstudio/sources/session...`. You can try fixing ownership/permissions per Phil's suggestion. Alternatively, if you went so far as reinstalling RStudio, you can blow away the entire directory `~/.local/share/rstudio`:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/rstudio
```

Comment: I noticed that the folder it wants to acces indeed does not exist. It wants “ session-97cc9b94”, but only another session folder is there, namely “session-fd38b68c”.      The thing with permissions did not help (of course if the folder it’s looking for is non existent), and when i was deleting rstudio before I wiped away the directory as well.

Comment: If that did not help, you could also try deleting "~/Library/Application\ Support/RStudio", "~/Library/Saved Application State/com.rstudio.desktop.savedState", "~/Library/Saved Application State/org.rstudio.RStudio.savedState".